# Grafana Failed to evaluate queries and expressions: input data must be a wide series but got type not (input refid)

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I have one clickhouse script:

```
SELECT
    d AS day,
    awg_redirect_id,
    count(*) AS hits
FROM
    input_data.dil
WHERE
    puid IS NOT NULL AND day >= toDateTime($from) AND day <= toDateTime($to)
GROUP BY
    day,
    awg_redirect_id
ORDER BY
    day ASC,
    awg_redirect_id
```

Everything is drawn beautifully on the graph. When I try to set up alerts an error occurs

```
Error
Failed to evaluate queries and expressions: input data must be a wide series but got type not (input refid)
```

My dashboard look like:
[image]

[image]

I don't know which way to think, because all formats seem to be clear. I want to set an alert at all, that if the average value for the past week differs from the current value by `50%`, then issue an alert.